# Getting data from Mapire.eu (website) to QGIS

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to get data from this web site ([mapire.eu](https://mapire.eu/)) to QGIS?

I want to make a historical map of rivers in 18th and 19th century compared to today but cant find a way to import data.

I am new to QGIS.

Comment: Yes via the *paid* WMTS service https://mapire.eu/en/wmts/ ... then in QGIS Go to Layer | Add Layer | Add WMS/WMTS Server > https://freegistutorial.com/how-to-add-wmts-layer-on-qgis/

Answer (score 3):

The website you are looking at seems to be designed to sell you raw data through its Buy button, or to enable you to view its maps using its viewer.

To view its web maps in QGIS, you could potentially add them as a WMS/WMTS, but that will only work if they provide one.

It looks like they do provide a [commercial WMTS](https://mapire.eu/en/wmts/).